# Guitar pedals not passing clean signal when bypassed

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I just went through four of my foot pedals and each one works when the effect is engaged. But when the footswitch is clicked... silence. I can't believe all three miraculously have this exact same problem at once. I am using a wall adapter rated at 9.6 volts DC, an older cable connected to the input, and a short cable for the output. Like I said, the sound and effect worked when the effect is engaged, but when the effect is turned off, there is no guitar.

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to answer without details on the actual pedals, but here is my theory:

3pdt (foot)switches, like in "*true bypass*" pedals, have a reputation for being unreliable. If you are attempting a DIY repair on a pedal like this, that's where i would look first.

In case the signal runs through a buffer when bypassed, check if the buffer circuit works properly, commonly a capacitor will dry up, or a bad solder joint will degrade over time.